# Проверка двух паролей на идентичность

Tags: c#, wpf, пароль

Как проверить два пароля на идентичность, чтобы можно было отображать ошибку (`validation rule` или реализация `IDataErrorInfo`)?

Comment: Вы имеете в виду сравнение строк?

Comment: В принципе, да. Важно чтобы я смог отобразить ошибку с помощью Validation.ErrorTemplate

Comment: Ну, пусть ваша viewmodel имплементирует `IDataErrorInfo`. http://www.codearsenal.net/2012/06/wpf-textbox-validation-idataerrorinfo.html

Comment: Тут немножко не то. Мне нужна проверка в textbox'ах именно, сравнивать значения их текста друг с другом и в случае ошибки отображать ошибку. Не в классе, созданном EntityFramework'ом же работать с неизвестными ему textbox'ами...

Comment: Постойте, откуда тут взялся Entity Framework? Модель нам вообще неинтересна, на интересует viewmodel. А почему не покатит решение с `IDataErrorInfo`?

Comment: Не очень разбираюсь в терминологии, что конкретно здесь понимать под viewmodel? Про Entity Framework я не указал. В конкретном случае редактируются записи пользователя. Не думаю, что логику проверки следует встроить в сущность USER(для проверки имени пользователя как раз реализовал в классе USER проверку на пустое имя и уже существующее, реализовав IDataErrorInfo. В голове не укладывается пока, где (на каком уровне) можно сравнить два TextBox...

Comment: Вам не нужно сравнивать текст-боксы. У вьюмодели должно быть 2 поля - "пароль" и "подтверждение". При их изменении если они не совпадают - генерировать событие ошибки.

Answer (score 2):

В комментариях к вопросу саму идею Вам объяснили. А я попробую на примере.
Для начала, поведение, которого вы хотите достичь, в WPF лучше всего решается с помощью шаблона [MVVM](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-View-ViewModel). Приведу выдержку

> Шаблон MVVM делится на три части:
>
> **Модель (англ. Model)**, так же, как в
>   классической MVC, Модель представляет собой фундаментальные данные,
>   необходимые для работы приложения.
>
> **Представление (англ. View)** — это
>   графический интерфейс, то есть окно, кнопки и т. п. Представление
>   является подписчиком на событие изменения значений свойств или команд,
>   предоставляемых Моделью представления. В случае, если в Модели
>   представления изменилось какое-либо свойство, то она оповещает всех
>   подписчиков об этом, и Представление, в свою очередь, запрашивает
>   обновленное значение свойства из Модели представления. В случае, если
>   пользователь воздействует на какой-либо элемент интерфейса,
>   Представление вызывает соответствующую команду, предоставленную
>   Моделью представления.
>
> **Модель представления (англ. ViewModel)**
>   является, с одной стороны, абстракцией Представления, а с другой,
>   предоставляет обёртку данных из Модели, которые подлежат связыванию.
>   То есть, она содержит Модель, которая преобразована к Представлению, а
>   также содержит в себе команды, которыми может пользоваться
>   Представление, чтобы влиять на Модель.

Итого у нас получается, что классы EntityFramework - модели (Model), различные элементы управления - представления (View). Не хватает нам "прослойки" между ними, именуемой моделью представления (ViewModel), которая будет оборачивать нашу модель, для того, чтобы с ней могла работать View.

Ну-с приступим

Пусть модель у нас выглядит как-нибудь так:

```
class User
{
   public int Id { get; set; }

   public string Login { get; set; }

   public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Тут, думаю, все ясно. Теперь для этой модели нам нужна ViewModel. Она, во-первых, должна предоставлять данные модели для View (при этом контролируя корректность этих самых данных), а во-вторых, реализовывать бизнес-логику, предоставляемую через команды.

В WPF ViewModel должны реализовывать интерфейс INotifyPropertyChanged, для того, чтобы View узнавала об изменении данных во ViewModel. По хорошему лучше взять какой-нибудь фреймворк, например [MVVM Light](https://mvvmlight.codeplex.com), там уже есть базовый класс для ViewModel с необходимым функционалом. Я же приведу пример без него.

Для упрощения я буду делать без всякой оглядки на безопасность, пароли будут хранится открыто в строковом виде, а вводится в обычный `TextBox`. По хорошему хранить бы хэши паролей, а ввод делать через PasswordBox.
Так же я буду использовать `ValieationRule` - мне этот подход больше нравится.

```
public class UserVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   private readonly User _user; // Модель, которую будем оборачивать
   // т.к. поле повторного ввода не нужно модели, мы его вводим тут
   private string _repeatPassword;

   public UserVM(User user)
   {
      if (user == null)
         throw new ArgumentNullException("User model");
      _user = user;
   }

   // Реализуем интерфейс INotifyPropertyChanged
   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

   // Вспомогательная функция, для генерации события изменения свойства
   public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
   {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
   }

   public string Login
   {
      get { return _user.Login; }
      set
      {
         if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) // Не разрешаем указать пустой логин
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
         if (_user.Login == value)
            return;
         _user.Login = value;
         RaisePropertyChanged("Login"); // Сообщаем о том, что поле изменилось
      }
   }

   public string Password
   {
      get { return _user.Password; }
      set
      {
         if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) // Не разрешаем указать пустой пароль
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
         if (_user.Password == value)
            return;
         _user.Password = value;
         RaisePropertyChanged("Password"); // Сообщаем о том, что поле изменилось
      }
   }

   public string RepeatPassword
   {
      get { return _repeatPassword; }
      set
      {
         if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) // Не разрешаем указать пустой пароль
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
         if (value != Password) // Тут, собственно,и выполняется проверка на совпадение. Если не совпало, генерируем исключение
            throw new ArgumentException("Пароли не совпали");
         if (_repeatPassword == value)
            return;
         _repeatPassword = value;
         RaisePropertyChanged("RepeatPassword"); // Сообщаем о том, что поле изменилось
      }
   }

   // Еще много-много кода
}
```

Теперь описываем View, при этом не забывая проставлять `ValidatesOnExceptions`. Опишу только сами поля:

```
<Grid DataContext="{Binding ...}">
      <Grid.RowsDefinition>
         <RowDefinition/>
         <RowDefinition/>
         <RowDefinition/>
      </Grid.RowsDefinition>
      <Grid.ColumnsDefinition>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
      </Grid.ColumnsDefinition>

      <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="Логин: "/>
      <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=Login, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}"/>

      <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="Пароль: "/>
      <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=Password, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}"/>

      <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="Повторите пароль: "/>
      <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=RepeatPassword, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}"/>
   </Grid>
```

Вот собственно и все. Так же можно для TextBox'ов описать ErrorTemplate. Погуглите на эту тему, в сети достаточно информации.

**P.S.** Писал "на коленке", поэтому могут быть неточности

Comment: если Model - это просто данные, ViewModel - это UI-логика, то где находится бизнес-логика? а не проще INotifyPropertyChanged реализовать в классе User, и не создавать класс-обертку для User?

Comment: User - это модель, она вообще ничего не должна знать ни о ViewModel ни о View. > а не проще INotifyPropertyChanged реализовать в классе User, и не создавать класс-обертку для User? На первый взгляд может показаться, что проще, но как только проект начнет расти простота превращается в занозу в известном месте

Comment: _"User - это модель"_ -- т.е. просто данные. UserVM - это ViewModel, в котором реализована UI-логика. но где находится бизнес-логика? например, где реализовать простое бизнес-правило: if user.Password.Length < 6 then throw "too short".

Comment: Во ViewModel, там и бизнес логика. UI логику при желании можно реализовать только во View, там есть триггеры. Но обычно делается композиция - часть UI-логики во ViewModel, часть во View. Некоторые правила UI-логики проще реализовать во ViewModel

Comment: _"Во ViewModel, там и бизнес логика."_ -- а т.к. ViewModel и View сильно связаны, то получается, что бизнес-логика также привязана к UI, и является непереносимой. т.е. модель и бизнес-логику из wpf приложения нельзя просто взять и перенести, например, в asp.net mvc.

Comment: ViewModel о View тоже ничего не должна знать. Она просто предоставляет данные так, чтобы с ними было удобнее работать во View. Например можно ввести флаг IsPasswordCorrect вместо генерации исключений в сеттере, а View уже будет биндится на это свойство и, скажем, прятать/показывать сообщение. При этом никто не мешает в качестве View взять форму ASP, по идее никаких проблем быть не должно. Повторю, Model не знает ни о ViewModel, ни о View, ViewModel знает только о Mode, а View знает только о ViewModel

Comment: _"ViewModel о View тоже ничего не должна знать."_ -- я так понимаю, что View - это xaml. ViewModel - это xaml.cs. получается что обработчики разных событий находятся во ViewModel. или нет?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34654/discussion-between-donil-and-stack).

Answer (score -3):

Если вы имели ввиду сравнивать тексты `textBox`, то это совсем не сложно:

```
private void ConfirmTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!ConfirmTextBox.Equals(PasswordTextBox.Text))
    {
        labelResult.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        labelResult.Text = "Paroli ne sootvetstvuyut..";
    }
}
```